# Variable declaration in perl

Tags: perl

i have assigned a global variable at start of my script which is empty string and i assigned a value to that inside subroutine . When the script enters the  subroutine second time that variable is null and assigned new value .

I need to have the variable name constant for some subroutine calls and then change the value in the subroutine when my condition match

## first time it call the subroutine this variable will be empty enter the loop and in the loop i will assign the variable.. next time when it  enter the sub routine i want to use that variable value until the condition is met .

Here is the sample code

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl 
my $Next_5minus = '';

sub write_alog {
if (my $Next_5minus eq '') 
{
 ........
 .........
 }
 elsif ( $start_mtime < $end_mtime )
 {
 say $fh join("\n", @$alog);
 }
 elsif ( $start_mtime > $end_mtime )
 {
      
 my $Next_5minus = <will assign value>
 ..........
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little hard to understand, because you are describing code we can't see. Please edit the question to add [a simple but verifiable example of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with the current and desired result.

Comment: Try removing all your "my"s before the variable name, except the first one (the one at the outermost top level), if you are looking to have a single global variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want people to help you with your problems, it's polite to make it as simple as possible for them to help you. As a minimum, you should do the following:

1. Provide a short, self-contained, runnable program that demonstrates your problem.
2. Clean up the indentation in your code to make it easy to follow.
3. Add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code and clean up the problems they point out.

In this case, I suspect you'll see warnings about variables that mask variables of the same name. You define three copies of your `$Next_5minus` variable. Each of them will be initialised as `undef` as it is created and will disappear as it goes out of scope.

Try removing the extraneous `my` statements from your code and see if that fixes your problem.